# Recycle boost::beast io_context to perform non network communication tasks

Tags: c++, boost, asio, beast

I’d like to extend my work queue that is based on io_context, so it’ll perform also sync/async tasks that doesn’t involve network communication … So here’s how I define the consumer threads

```
// class members 
  boost::thread_group workers_;
  boost::asio::io_context ioc_;

// the main run method
  for (size_t i = 1; i < kThreads; ++i) {
    workers_.create_thread([this]() {
      ioc_.run();
    });
  }
  ioc_.run();
  workers_.join_all();
```

and here are some usage examples for serial commands

```
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
....
strand_(boost::asio::make_strand(ioc_))
....
boost::asio::post(strand_, [=]() { auto resp = doSomeStuffInForeground());
```

and parallel

```
  boost::asio::spawn(ioc_, [=](const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) {
    doSomeStuffInBackground(yield);
  });
```

And now my program have more tasks rather than network communication, and I’d like to recycles those iocontext related threads to operate them as well (i.e. to put non communication related code inside `doSomeStuffBackground` and/or `doSomeStuffForeground`). I wonder if it’s a good approach…

Also, I wonder if I can define some priority tasks that have precedence on other tasks
And last, I wonder if I can aggregate/merge several tasks from the queue that are similar.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: I have done non network related things in an `io_context` that primarily did networking. It probably is up to you to decide if this is the best way for your application though. And yes you can implement priority queues: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp

Finally, I don't quite know how you would ensure of one task of lower priority is executed before a task of higher priority, but where the higher priority task depends on the other task. Perhaps someone who is an expert with asio can elucidate us.

Comment: I'd post exactly as you did. In practice, I find that a single thread (separate io_context) is enough for all IO tasks - and I have another context (`asio::thread_pool`) to perform other tasks. W.r.t priorities, a classical queue can be easier (which is what I do in production) but Asio examples has an example with a custom executor that manages prioritized tasks)